# Getting array of results only in scope, not outside of scope

Tags: javascript

I am trying to receive an array of results from a function as follows:

```
getSearchLocation(){
    let results = [];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        console.log("in scope", results);
        return results;
    });
console.log("out of scope", results);
}
```

"in scope" results returns the array as it should be.

"out of scope" results returns a length: 0 empty array.

If I returned `results` array from `geocoder.geocode()`, isn't it supposed to assign it to the declared results array in `getSearchLocation()`?

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: @HassanImam - thx for reference. do I need to chain `.then()`?

Comment: You can return a promise from your function `getSearchLocation()`, resolve it inside `then()` in the function where you are calling it. You can also use `async -await`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
getSearchLocation(){
    let results = [];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        console.log("in scope", results); <== Line 1
         
    });
console.log("out of scope", results); <== Lin 2
}
```

Take a look at  the lines that I marked in the snippet. In Line 1, you are logging the results of callback of `geocoder.geocode` while in line 2 you are logging the empty array you just declared above. \

Moreover if you are assuming that it would contain the results you better assign the return value to it. Something like

```js
getSearchLocation(){
    let results = [];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(data, status) {
        results = data;
        console.log("out of scope", results);
        
    });

}
```

Comment: hey George, I liked what you wrote, thanks, but the last line there: `console.log("out of scope", results);` is still in scope, with this construct, how would I be able to assign `geocoder.geocode()` results to `getSearchLocation()` results?